# Lithium ion batteries , any way to predict how much the voltage will vary due to heat after a discharge?

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion

I've noticed from monitoring a lithium ion battery pack that after a discharge, the voltage seems to continually rise (in the timespan of hours/days) and then stabilize after some time. The more the discharge current, the longer it takes for this voltage stabilization to happen.
I'm assuming it is due to an unfinished chemical reaction in the battery due to the residual heat.

Is there any way to roughly predict how long it will take for a lithium ion battery voltage to stabilize, given a known temperature and/or discharge current?

Comment: FYI, this is called *relaxation*. And it's not due to heat. Because if it were due to heat you could replicate the effect by heating or cooling the battery externally.

Comment: ... and this is why gas-gauge ICs exist, as voltage alone is a very poor predictor of state of charge

Comment: @DKNguyen This is the first time I've heard of the term, thanks. Going by a brief description here (https://www.eng.mcmaster.ca/sites/default/files/uploads/eecomobility_2019_poster_mmessing.pdf): "In lithium-ion batteries, different
lithium-ion concentration gradients exist throughout the battery after discharge or charge is stopped. These concentration gradients naturally tend to equalize themselves over time." // Doesn't that imply relaxation is due to the charge/discharge heat affecting the chemicals in the battery? I'll try to read more reliable sources on the subject when possible.

Comment: @plu Not necessarily. More happens during discharge than just heat.